# How to find table row after modal open close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have form which I have a table and in the table there are rows or I will add rows dynamically.

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-light sortable" >
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">{{ __('additional_information.title') }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ __('additional_information.text') }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ __('additional_information.file') }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ __('additional_information.is_public') }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ __('additional_information.is_showcase') }}</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
   @foreach ($additionalInformations as $additionalInformation)
            <tr>
                <td data-value="{{ $additionalInformation->title }}">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('additional_information.title') }}" name="existing_additional_information_title[{{ $additionalInformation->id }}]" value='{{ $additionalInformation->title }}'>
                </td>
                <td data-value="{{ $additionalInformation->text }}">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="{{ __('additional_information.text') }}" name="existing_additional_information_texts[{{ $additionalInformation->id }}]" value='{{ $additionalInformation->text }}'>
                </td>
                <td  id = "photo"  class="d-inline-block text-truncate" data-value="{{ $additionalInformation->original_file_name }}" style="max-width: 300px;">
   @empty($additionalInformation->original_file_name)
   @else
                    <a href="/file/image/{{ $additionalInformation->file }}"    data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<img src='/file/image/{{ $additionalInformation->file }}'  width='180'  >">{{ $additionalInformation->original_file_name }} </a>
@endif<br>
                <input type="file"  class= "imgcha" name="existing_additional_information_files[{{ $additionalInformation->id }}]"><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-img file center-block"  id ="add_id" value="{{ $additionalInformation->id }}" name="file_photo"/>Rajaa näyttökuva </button>

                </td>
                <td nowrap data-value="{{ $additionalInformation->existing_additional_information_is_publics }}">
                    <label class="plain"><input type="checkbox" name="existing_additional_information_is_publics[{{ $additionalInformation->id }}]" value="1" {{ $additionalInformation->is_public == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('additional_information.is_public') }}</label>
                </td>
                <td nowrap data-value="{{ $additionalInformation->existing_additional_information_is_showcase }}">
                    <label class="plain"><input type="checkbox" name="existing_additional_information_is_showcase[{{ $additionalInformation->id }}]" value="1" {{ $additionalInformation->is_showcase == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('additional_information.is_showcase') }}</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary delete" value = {{ $additionalInformation->id }}><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> {{ __('global.delete') }}</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
   @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

or

        var number= 0;
        $(".add-new").click(function(){
            // Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

            var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
            var row =
                '<tr>' +
                '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __("additional_information.title") }}" name="new_additional_information_title[]" value=""></td>' +
                '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __("additional_information.text") }}" name="new_additional_information_texts[]" value=""></td>' +

                '<td class="d-inline-block text-truncate"><input  type="file" class= "imgcha" name="new_additional_information_files[]" ><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-img file center-block" value="{{ $additionalInformation->id ?? null}}" id ="add_id" name="file_photo">Rajaa näyttökuva </button> </td>' +
                ' <input type="hidden"  name="new_additional_information_is_publics[' + number + ']" value="0" /> ' +
                '<td nowrap><label class="plain"><input type="checkbox" name="new_additional_information_is_publics[' + number + ']"value="1" checked> {{ __("additional_information.is_public") }}</label></td>' +
                '<td nowrap><label class="plain"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="new_additional_information_is_showcase[]" value="1"> {{ __("additional_information.is_showcase") }}</label></td>' +
                '<td><button class="btn btn-secondary delete" value="0"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> {{ __("global.delete") }}</button></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $("table").append(row);
            $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            number++;
        });
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LQxM.png)

After I add a row I click a button which opens modal. In the modal I crop image and send/save the cropped image via ajax. In return I get path to the picture. The I want to add a hidden input to the clicked row like

```
            resize.croppie('result', {

                type: 'canvas',

                size: 'viewport'

            }).then(function (img) {
                    console.log( 'toka');
                $.ajax({

                    url: "{{route('upload.image')}}",

                    type: "POST",

                    data: {"image":img, "add_id":add_id},

                    success: function (data) {

                        var el = '<input type="hidden" name="crop_img" value=' 
                        + data.path + '></input>';
                        $('#additionalInformationForm 
           input:hidden:last').replaceWith(el);

                        var test = $('#additionalInformationForm 
        tr:last').val();
                            console.log(data.id + data.path +test);


                    }

                });

            });

        });
modal
<div class="modal fade " id="cropImagePop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered " role="document"  >
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:750px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Croppaa 
       näyttökuva</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
       label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body align-items-center text-center" >
                <div id="upload-demo"></div>
                <button type = "button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block 
            `enter code here`upload-image" style="margin-top:2%">Rajaa 
             kuva</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the question is how can i find the right row where to add the input? And how to update certain row everytime time i crop the photo.
Hopefully you can understand the question. Thanks!

[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDuZn.png)

```
  public function uploadImage(Request $request)

    {

        if($request->add_id === null){
            $image = $request->image;

            list($type, $image) = explode(';', $image);

            list(, $image)      = explode(',', $image);

            $image = base64_decode($image);

            $image_name= time().'.png';


            $path = storage_path() . '/app/additional_information_files/' . $image_name;


            $statement = DB::select("show table status like 'additional_informations'");



            file_put_contents($path, $image);
            $path_img = '/app/additional_information_files/' . $image_name;
           // $filename = explode("/", $path);
            //$path_img = 'file/image/' . $filename[8];
            return response()->json(['status'=>true, 'path' => $path, 'id'=>  $statement[0]->Auto_increment]);
        }

        $addinfo = \App\AdditionalInformation::find($request->add_id);
        $image = $request->image;


        if($addinfo->showcase_picture)
        {
            Storage::delete($addinfo->showcase_picture);
        }
        list($type, $image) = explode(';', $image);

        list(, $image)      = explode(',', $image);

        $image = base64_decode($image);

        $image_name= time().'.png';


        $path = storage_path() . '/app/additional_information_files/' . $image_name;


        $addinfo->showcase_picture = $path;
        $addinfo->save();

        file_put_contents($path, $image);

        return response()->json(['status'=>true, 'path' => $path]);

    }

    public function createFromRequest(Request $request, AdditionalInformationContainer $container)
    {
        // Get texts, files and isPublics from the request
        $titles = $request->get('new_additional_information_title') ?? [];
        $texts = $request->get('new_additional_information_texts') ?? [];
        $files = $request->file('new_additional_information_files') ?? [];
        $isPublics = $request->get('new_additional_information_is_publics') ?? [];
        $isShowcases = $request->get('new_additional_information_is_showcase') ?? [];
        $isCropImages = $request->get('crop_img') ?? [];
        // Validate files
        $this->validateFiles($request);


        // Loop through all texts and get the matching files and isPublics
        // based on the array index
        foreach ($texts as $index => $text) {
            $title = array_key_exists($index, $titles) ? $titles[$index] : null;
            $text = array_key_exists($index, $texts) ? $texts[$index] : null;
            $file = array_key_exists($index, $files) ? $files[$index] : null;
            $isPublic = array_key_exists($index, $isPublics) ? $isPublics[$index] : false;
            $isShowcase = array_key_exists($index, $isShowcases) ? $isShowcases[$index] : false;
            $isCropImage = array_key_exists($index, $isCropImages) ? $isCropImages[$index] : false;

            // If the fields are empty, skip
            if ($text === null && $file === null) {
                continue;
            }

            // Create the additional information and attach it to the container
            $additionalInformation = $this->create($file, $title, $text, $isPublic, $isShowcase, $isCropImage);

            if ($additionalInformation) {
                $container->additionalInformations()->attach($additionalInformation);
            }
        }

        return $container;
    }

    public function create(UploadedFile $file = null, string $title = null, string $text = null, bool $isPublic, bool $isShowcase, string $isCropImage = null)
    {
        // Skip if file and text are empty
        if (!$file && strlen(trim($text)) === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create the additional information with basic info
        $additionalInformation = new AdditionalInformation();
        $additionalInformation->title = $title;
        $additionalInformation->text = $text;
        $additionalInformation->is_public = $isPublic;
        $additionalInformation->is_showcase = $isShowcase;
        $additionalInformation->showcase_picture = $isCropImage;
        // Attach the file if specified
        if ($file) {
            $path = $file->store('additional_information_files');
            $additionalInformation->file = $path;
            $additionalInformation->filesize = $file->getClientSize();
            $additionalInformation->original_file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        }
        // Save
        $additionalInformation->save();
        return $additionalInformation;
    }
~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using similar tactics. What you can do is simply mark the `<tr>` with a data attribute containing the id of the model you're listing (or something unique for every record). Then, in your server part, once the changes have been done, just generate the `<tr>` anew (you can export it to a separate file for that purpose) and return it as data with the response. Then in your jquery just find the tr marked with the unique data attribute and `.replaceWith()` the new tr returned... or modify it however you like!

Hope you got it, I can't provide an example since we're lacking your server side logic... but that's the point at all.

Comment: Added logic. I dont quite understand sorry. I only save the cropped image with ajax, rest of the table/form will be saved after button "valmis" click. So each row has two pictures, one is chosen by input and the other should be in the hiddden field so i can  save that also in the same db row.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem with the above code.

Added a hidden input after when adding row. And when I was cropping photo I added value "in_edit" and after I saved the cropped image I find that value and replaced it with the path to the image. And saved that with the form accordingly. Needed some thinking!! Thanks Petrov for the pointing me to right path:)

jquery

```
  $(document).on('click', '.item-img', function (e) {

            if(ch_image  ===  undefined) {
                ch_image = $(this).closest('tr').find('a').attr('href');

            }

                add_id= $(this).val();
             $(this).closest('tr').find("[name='crop_img[]']").attr('value', 'in_edit');
             $(this).closest('tr').find("[name='new_Crop_Img[]']").attr('value', 'new_in_edit');


            $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');

        });

      $('.crop_img').each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('value') == 'in_edit'){

                                $(this).attr('value', data.path)
                                console.log('if');
                            }

                        });

                        $('.new_crop_img').each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('value') == 'new_in_edit'){

                                $(this).attr('value', data.path)
                                console.log('if');
                            }

                        });



        var number= 0;
        $(".add-new").click(function(){
            // Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

            var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
            var row =
                '<tr>' +
                '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __("additional_information.title") }}" name="new_additional_information_title[]" value=""></td>' +
                '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{ __("additional_information.text") }}" name="new_additional_information_texts[]" value=""></td>' +

                '<td class="d-inline-block text-truncate"><input  type="file" class= "imgcha" name="new_additional_information_files[]" ></td>' +
                ' <input type="hidden"  name="new_additional_information_is_publics[' + number + ']" value="0" /> ' +
                '<td nowrap><label class="plain"><input type="checkbox" name="new_additional_information_is_publics[' + number + ']"value="1" checked> {{ __("additional_information.is_public") }}</label></td>' +
                '<td nowrap><label class="plain"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="new_additional_information_is_showcase[]" value="1"> {{ __("additional_information.is_showcase") }}<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary item-img file center-block" value="{{ $additionalInformation->id ?? null}}" id ="add_id" name="file_photo">Rajaa näyttökuva </button> </label></td>' +
                '<td><button class="btn btn-secondary delete" value="0"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> {{ __("global.delete") }}</button></td>' +
                ' <input type="hidden" class="new_crop_img"  name="new_Crop_Img[]"></input></tr>';
            $("table").append(row);
            $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            number++;
        });


        $(document).on('change','.chk' ,function() {
            console.log('vaihda');
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('.chk').not(this).each(function() {
                    $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    console.log('if');
                });
            }




        });
    });

~~~~
```